# Next Thursday is vacation

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have read the following sentence in a language learning tool (the Italian course in Duolingo) :

> Next Thursday is vacation.

What does it mean?

It sounds odd to me, either in US English or UK English. I think it might be a bad translation. I'd rather say:

- the holidays are next week/month (holidays = "festivities of the end of the year" or holiday = "day in which most schools, stores and offices are closed because of a public celebration" )
- the holiday is next Thursday ( holiday = "day in which most schools, stores and offices are closed because of a public celebration")
- the holiday(s) (UK) / vacation (US) start(s) next Thursday (holiday(s)/vacation = "rest period given to a specific student/worker or group of those")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems incorrect!

Vacation is a **period** and not a *day.* Generally, when you say that you are on a vacation, you mean it is more than a day. Hence, mentioning *Thursday*, only one day, for a vacation does not satisfy the definition we have in dictionaries.

Yes, this is a valid sentence...

> Next Thursday is a holiday!

Or...

> The vacation begins *from* next Thursday.

Comment: I think that the preposition "from" is optional in "The vacation begins from next Thursday" ?

Comment: It can be spoken and not sound incorrect but I don’t know the grammar. For example, “Do you want to see a movie Thursday? / Next Thursday is vacation - how about Wednesday? / Wednesday night is yoga, so that’s not good for me.”